# Auto filter spreadsheet gear

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetgear

I have an auto filter set on a range of cells in excel, however i want to be able to choose the drop down criteria too.

```
//Autofilter Cells
IRange fundfilter = prodworkbook.Worksheets["Funds"].Cells["A4:L2000"];
fundfilter.AutoFilter();
```

The auto filter method adds the filter to the data, but i want to be able to select a criteria of say "Hedge funds" to column C's filter. Is this possible? Language C#, using Spreadsheet gear framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the IRange.[AutoFilter](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~AutoFilter.html)() method is overloaded, which provides the extra parameters you'd need to do this.  Example:

```
fundfilter.AutoFilter(2, "Hedge funds", AutoFilterOperator.Or, null, true);
```

See the following Silverlight sample for more examples of using this auto filter API:
http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/silverlight.aspx?InitSample=SilverlightSamples.Range.AutoFilterSample

The SpreadsheetGear for .NET and SpreadsheetGear for Silverlight products share much of the same underlying core APIs, so this example is relevant for either products.